# Neutron Spin and external magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, neutrons

I know as a fact that neutrons have spin 1/2, as spin is an angular momentum it should couple with an external magnetic field, so that means that the neutron is interacting with B and has q=0, so iḿ confused is this interaction an electromagnetic one and im forgeting that neutron has an internal structure and so it has a local charge (maybe the quarks)? or just a property of angular momentum?

Answer (score 0):

It is a consequence of the fact that there are three teeny little guys (i.e., quarks, in a bound state with no specific quantum numbers) running around in circles at top speed inside what we call a neutron, and that those little guys carry charge, and that their individual magnetic moments will be so distributed as to sum to a consistent nonzero value as measured from outside the neutron.

Comment: The phrase “at any particular instant” might give the misimpression that the neutron’s magnetic moment is not a constant; it is in fact about 50 nano-eV per tesla at every instant.

Comment: @rob  maybe add to that that the neutron is in a bound state of the constituent quarks etc, and bound states have specific quantum number values.

Comment: @ rob, will edit. -NN

Comment: @anna v, will edit. -NN